# Prevent body scrolling when the user scrolls on fixed position div

Tags: html, css, scroll

On mobile devices when a `position:fixed;` element appears on the screen the user can scroll the `<body>`, through the fixed element.

```
body,
html{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#fixed {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    background: blue;
    height: 3000px;
}
```

I tried to add `overflow:hidden` for `<html>` and `<body>` but it didn't help. I would like to prevent scrolling through the fixed element, but I would like to allow the scroll, when the fixed element is visible, but the user scrolls on `<body>`.

I tried this with ios and android devices. What is the best solution to solve this?

Comment: Any answers for this? CSS only solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
background:fixed
```

will make the rest of the body scroll through the fixed element. That is is the default behaviour. By the looks of it, you want the fixed element to be positioned at the top of your page. Why not keep it is a separate container with position absolute and rest of the body in a different container. Then, add the scroll to the rest of the body keeping HTML, body at 100% height. you may need to keep the height fixed for the 2nd container.

Comment: It's not about the background. I would like to prevent the scrolling on body.

Comment: Can you please share a working link of your problem. It will be great help to provide accurate answer